# How to get models in different categories via monads

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra, monads

Consider an infinitary algebraic theory.

It can be represented by a category $\mathcal{T}$ with finite products, where models in a category $\mathcal{X}$ are functors $\mathcal{T}\to \mathcal{X}$ preserving finite products and morphisms between models are natural transformations. By varying the category $\mathcal{X}$ we can get models of $\mathcal{T}$ in different categories.

It can also be represented by a monad $T$ on $\mathsf{Set}$ given by free-forgetful-adjunction.

> How can we do the same thing with monads? I.e: how can we get a monad $T'$ on a category $\mathcal{X}$ from the monad $T$ on $\mathsf{Set}$, such that the Eilenberg-Moore category of $T'$ is equivalent to the category of models of $\mathcal{T}$ in $\mathcal{X}$?

Comment: Have you encountered classifying toposes? You might find the relevant chapter of *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* useful, if not to get an explicit answer, then at least as a more structured context to think about the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean *finitary* algebraic theories, since you talk about finite products (though an analogous statement holds for small products), it is proven on the nLab page [multisorted Lawvere theories](https://ncatlab.org/toddtrimble/published/multisorted+Lawvere+theories) that given a finitary $S$-sorted algebraic theory $\mathcal T$, if $\mathcal C$ is cocomplete and admits finite products distributing over colimits, then the forgetful functor $\mathrm{Mod}(\mathcal T, \mathcal C) \to \mathcal C^S$ is monadic, i.e. equivalent to the category of algebras for a monad on $\mathcal C^S$.